# Size in bytes is significantly less ( half the size) then size in MB in get info window

Tags: macos, command-line, folders, filesystem, file

In the get info window it says 387,037,139 bytes which is 387 MB whereas the size on disk is 716.9MB which is 716,900,000 bytes.

`du -sh paramgen`  result (in MiB) `684M    paramgen`

Why is there such a large difference?

[image: get_info screen]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

387,037,139 bytes is the sum of the file lengths in bytes. A file however uses whole blocks on disk, hence even a one byte file takes one block. On the partition on which I tested this, a block is 4K. The “on disk” value is the number of blocks times the block size.

The difference between 684 and 716.9 is a factor of 1.024*1.024, that is the difference between the two possible meanings of megabyte.