# 127 million bytes but 204MB on disk?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

[image]

Am I missing something basic or is this a bug ?

Comment: This question unnecessarily relies on an image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Size in bytes is significantly less ( half the size) then size in MB in get info window](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112015/size-in-bytes-is-significantly-less-half-the-size-then-size-in-mb-in-get-info)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's not beyond the realms of possibility. Allocation block size is 4k. If every file was 5k, then they'd each take up 8k on disk, which gives 218MB.

Comment: To expound on that point: I had a situation with about a million or so small files, each about 1KB, which due to the block size, ended up taking up over 4 GB instead of <1 GB, on disk.

Comment: The average file size is 4660.5 bytes, which would agree with your analysis. The average allocated space for each file is 7848.7 bytes

Answer (score 7):

If all the files are below the allocation block size of the disk by a lot, then that could make perfect sense.

27,254 items all below an allocation block size of 8,192 bytes would lead to an "on disk" size of about 213 MB.

Comment: APFS block size is 4k, so you'd need file sizes to spill over the first block to reach 8k.